# Remove string from StringReader

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to read some lines from a file and if the line contains a specific string to skip it then print the line.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("(tst)"))   
        Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

if my line is something like "lorem tst a btst c"
how can i make it to be displayed like "lorem a b c"?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Or just `line = "Whatever you want";`

Comment: What do you want to display if it's **not** “something like "lorem tst a btst c"”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line variable is of type `string`, so use its built in `Replace` function.

### UPDATE

Using regular expression to replace any extra white space in the middle of the string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);     

        string test = "lorem tst a btst c tst tst tst tst a";
        Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(test.Replace("tst", ""), @" "));
    }
}
```

Result:

> lorem a b c a

See working example here... https://dotnetfiddle.net/BXDZs6

Comment: What about "lorem tst a btst c tst tst tst tst a"?

Comment: @jdphenix Good catch...  Updated answer accounts for your suggested situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what RegexOptions is used for but i've used  "Console.WriteLine(line.Replace("(tst) ","")); " and it's working no matter how many (tst) strings are in the line

Comment: @Apollyon04 If you try the test string, that I used in my answer, your result will be lorem__a b c_____a.  There are two spaces between lorem & the first a, and there are five spaces between the c & last a.

Comment: @Shar1er80 is it possible to use this method to remove chars from the line depending on how many tst string are? ex: "loremtst a tst" to become "lore a"  or "loremtsttst" to "lor"

Comment: @Apollyon04 This method will remove all instance of "tst" regardless of how many there are.  It doesn't remove a specific amount.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit confused as to the exact result that you want, but [String.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might be what you're after.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("tst")) {
        string line = line.Replace("tst", "");
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```